# C# javascript reload all tabs in Panel

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using this to reload the active tab:

```
parent.parent.BodyPanel.activeTab.reload();
```

How I can reload all tabs of BodyPanel at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by reloading the whole page:

```
parent.parent.document.location.reload();
```